# Column name with a Space - Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to create a table that has a column name with Space using Athena Console.

Example: "Mag Creative" String

Error: This field is required. Spaces are not allowed!

Comment: I find it a too low-quality question. The question is not about programming, but an validation message in a form field. 
Also the error message is included in the question so the question and the answer are the same.
It is unlikely that it will help future readers

Answer (score 7):

You can try double quotes,like this:

```
SELECT i."interest expense" FROM "financial-analysis-tool"."income_statement"
```

Comment: This worked well for me for my column that had a period in it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Athena column names [cannot contain any other special character besides underscore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html), the error is prescriptive and explicit about what the problem is.  You *must* use an underscore for this column name instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use a space in the name of a table column; there are special rules for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was space in the column name
So I had to change the create table

```
create external table temp_table(
Open string,
High string,
Low string,
Close string,
"Adj Close"string...
```

to

```
create external table temp_table(
Open string,
High string,
Low string,
Close string,
adj_close string...
```